# Approximation of smooth diffeomorphisms by polynomial diffeomorphisms?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, inverse, approximation-theory, diffeomorphism

Is it possible to (locally) approximate an arbitrary smooth diffeomorphism by a *polynomial diffeomorphism*?

More precisely: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth diffeomorphism. For $U\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ bounded and open and $\varepsilon>0$, is there a *diffeomorphism* $p=(p_1, \cdots, p_d) : U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ (with inverse $q:=p^{-1} : p(U)\rightarrow U$) such that both

- $\|f - p\|_{\infty;\,U}:=\sup_{x\in U}|f(x) - p(x)| < \varepsilon$, $\ \textbf{and}$
- each component of $p$ and of $q=(q_1,\cdots,q_d)$is a polynomial, i.e. $p_i, q_i\in\mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_d]$ for each $i=1, \ldots, d$?

Clearly, by Stone-Weierstrass there is a polynomial map $p : \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|f - p\|_{\infty;\,U} < \varepsilon$ and such that $q:=(\left.p\right|_U)^{-1}$ exists; in general, however, this $q$ will not be a polynomial map.

Do you have any ideas/references under which conditions on $f$ an approximation of the above kind can be guaranteed nonetheless?

Comment: What do you mean by "locally" here? As you wrote it, I believe the claim doesn't hold in one dimension: in one dimension, the only polynomial diffeomorphisms are the linear functions. Then by making your $f$ sufficiently squiggly/nonlinear, the claim will be false.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @user757173. By "locally" I do indeed mean that (as stated) both $U$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent of one another (as opposed to "$\forall\, \varepsilon>0 \, \exists\, U=U_\varepsilon \subset\mathbb{R}^d : [\ldots]$," in which case the resulting claim should be trivial by the inverse function theorem).

Comment: As you remarked, the dimension $d$ seems crucial as it regulates "how many" polynomial diffeomorphisms there are, and I agree with your observation that for $d=1$, there aren't enough of them. While I would expect the "size" of the family of polynomial diffeos to increase quite rapidly with d (at least morally, by the Jacobian conjecture), so does the allowed 'complexity' of $f$, and it seems to me that there might be no $d$ for which there are enough poly. diffeos available to match the claim unless the complexity of $f$ is suitably restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Robert Bryant over at

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364099/approximation-of-smooth-diffeomorphisms-by-polynomial-diffeomorphisms ,

the answer to this question is 'no'.